# How to get the latest firefox on 10.04 after EOL?

Tags: 10.04, apt, firefox

I have a 10.04 desktop that has FireFox 13 installed. Whenever a new version came out it was updating, but after switching the sources list to the archive sources for 10.04 end of life, apt-get claims that FireFox is the latest version. My other 10.04 machines are running 17.

There was a PPA for the latest stable firefox, but I can't seem to find it any-more and some articles suggest it may have been discontinued?

What is the preferred way of keeping Firefox updated on EOL 10.04?

Comment: If you follow the instructions on the top answer you'll get firefox directly from Mozilla, it will then keep autoupdating on its own. Also consider upgrading to 12.04!

Comment: Is there any way to get it via apt or PPA? Our computers are run by unprivileged users, so it would be great if it were part of automatic updates.

Comment: I don't see one for 10.04 unfortunately.

Comment: What about `ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa`? Is that supported?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be possible by adding `ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa` to software sources and running `apt-get update` and `apt-get install firefox`. It also works for Thunderbird.